# Using Asus Xtion with electric failing depth stream

Tags: ros, kinect, asus

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey All,

I am trying to get my Asus Xtion working with electric using the `openni_launch` but I keep getting the following error;

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
what():  virtual void openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::startDepthStream() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-openni-  kinect-0.3.2/debian/ros-electric-openni-kinect/opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 257 : starting depth stream failed. Reason: Xiron OS got an event timeout!
```

I am starting the kinect using the standard procedure from the wiki as follows;

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

Then I start `rviz` using `rosrun rviz rviz`, and immediately when I set the Fixed frame to `/camera/depth_optical_frame` and the topic to `/camera/depth/points`, I get the error above. I have tried changing the usb ports and even doing a `sudo chmod 777 /dev/bus/usb` but no change so far.

Any suggestions are welcome.

P.S. The MS Kinect works without a problem though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12592/using-asus-xtion-with-electric-failing-depth-stream/) by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1295 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to download the latest OpenNI-Compliant Sensor Driver from http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-history-2/

Then I ran the install.sh script as superuser, first with the -u argument to uninstall it, and then run it without arguments to install it.

I didn't have the same problem that you have but I also had Xiron OS errors.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) with karma: 651 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0